# Copy a file to a different place with a new name with python

Tags: python, file-copying, file-move

I have a file in some location, and I want to copy that file to another location but with a different name. This operation will be repeated many times and in every case the basename of the file to copy is the same (only location varies) so that is why the renaming.

Anyway, a way to do this is explained in [this guide](https://pythonguides.com/python-copy-file/).
The code is

```
import shutil
import os

# Specify the source file, the destination for the copy, and the new name
source_file = 'path/to/your/source/file.txt'
destination_directory = 'path/to/your/destination/'
new_file_name = 'new_file.txt'

# Copy the file
shutil.copy2(source_file, destination_directory)

# Get the base name of the source file
base_name = os.path.basename(source_file)

# Construct the paths to the copied file and the new file name
copied_file = os.path.join(destination_directory, base_name)
new_file = os.path.join(destination_directory, new_file_name)

# Rename the file
os.rename(copied_file, new_file)
```

So far so good.
My question is by *only* using `os.rename` we would be able to *"move"* the file. Is copying really this complicated in comparison? Isn't some method to just copy and rename with a single command?

NOTE: Before someone flag this question as "repeated", notice that *I am giving the solution to the basic problem* right above.
What I am asking -and therefore not a repeat- is that if in terms of writing effective python, is not a simpler way of doing that.

Comment: From the documentation of shutil.copy `Copies the file src to the file or directory dst` - so isn't what you're after `shutil.copy2('path/to/your/source/file.txt', 'path/to/your/destination/new_file.txt')` ?

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, you provided some link to some (frankly dubious) source as "the solution". But that isn't the solution you would usually find, certainly not if you have looked for it on Stack Overflow. As already noted in the comments, you just want `shutil.copy2('path/to/your/source/file.txt', 'path/to/your/destination/new_file.txt')`, you can pass the *whole path to the new file with the new name* to `shutil.copy2`. I don't know why you were complicated it further, but you don't need that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. What you just wrote is the precise answer I was looking for.